# How to return temporary table from Stored Procedure in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2, database-migration

I need to create Stored Procedure in IBM DB2 in which we have to create temporary table and insert and delete some values to that temporary table and return temporary table.

**Stored Procedure in IBM DB2 gives following error**

DB2ADMIN.GETRECORDS - Deploy started.
Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
DB2ADMIN.GETRECORDS: 39: An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56
An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56
DB2ADMIN.GETRECORDS - Deploy failed.
DB2ADMIN.GETRECORDS - Roll back completed successfully.

**Below is the Stored Procedure in IBM DB2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETRECORDS ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
```

P1: BEGIN

```
-- temporary table declared 
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS
    (Column1 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column2 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column3 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column4 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Column5 FLOAT ,
     Column6 FLOAT ,
     Column7 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column8 FLOAT ,
     Column9 FLOAT ,
     Column10 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );

-- inserted data in temporary table
INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS 
    SELECT  VM.Column1,
            VM.Column2,
            VM.Column3,
            VM.Column4,
            VM.Column5,
            VM.Column6,
            VM.Column7,
            VM.Column8,
            VM.Column9,TRIM(VM.Column1) + TRIM(VM.Column2) + TRIM(VM.Column3)
    FROM    (SELECT * FROM  RECORDUNITS )
AS VM       

-- deleted data from temporary table
DELETE FROM  SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS 
WHERE TRIM(Column10) IN(SELECT TRIM(Column1) + TRIM(Column2) + TRIM(Column3) 
                    FROM OLDRECORDS);

-- trying to return temporary table
DECLARE entCursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT Column1, 
       Column2,
       Column3,
       Column4,
       Column5,
       Column6,
       Column7,
       Column8,
       Column9
    FROM SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS ORDER BY Column1;
OPEN entCursor1;
```

END P1

Comment: Is this a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68014632/how-to-return-temporary-table-from-function-in-ibm-db2? If yes, delete one of them

Answer (score 3):

You need to obey the [rules](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-compiled) for the order of statements in a compound-SQL compiled block.   Cursor declarations must come after other variable declarations and before other executable statements.

The DGTT can be defined later, and the cursor (which gets declared but not defined before the DGTT), can be later defined and prepared after the DGTT gets populated.

You may be able avoid a DGTT completely in this example, by using a query that returns from RECORDUNITS ... EXCEPT ...OLDRECORDS.  However, this answer shows one way to handle the DGTT cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETRECORDS ()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
   declare v_cursor_text varchar(1024);
   DECLARE entCursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Statement1;

   -- temporary table declared 
   DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS
    (Column1 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column2 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column3 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column4 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Column5 FLOAT ,
     Column6 FLOAT ,
     Column7 NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Column8 FLOAT ,
     Column9 FLOAT ,
     Column10 NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    ) with replace on commit preserve rows not logged ;

   -- inserted data in temporary table
    INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS
    SELECT  VM.Column1,
            VM.Column2,
            VM.Column3,
            VM.Column4,
            VM.Column5,
            VM.Column6,
            VM.Column7,
            VM.Column8,
            VM.Column9,TRIM(VM.Column1) + TRIM(VM.Column2) + TRIM(VM.Column3)
    FROM    (SELECT * FROM  RECORDUNITS ) AS VM;

    -- deleted data from temporary table
    DELETE FROM  SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS
    WHERE TRIM(Column10) IN(SELECT TRIM(Column1) + TRIM(Column2) + TRIM(Column3)
                    FROM OLDRECORDS);
    set v_cursor_text = 'SELECT Column1, 
       Column2,
       Column3,
       Column4,
       Column5,
       Column6,
       Column7,
       Column8,
       Column9
    FROM SESSION.TEMPRECORDDETAILS ORDER BY Column1' ;

    prepare Statement1 from v_cursor_text;

    
    OPEN entCursor1;

END P1
@
```